# mysqldump "Access denied" error on ubuntu with mariadb (login informations are correct)

Tags: server, mysql, mariadb

I use Ubuntu with a mariadb database.

I want to make a mysqldump of my sql databases, but i get allways the following error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045; "Access denied for user 'db_user-backups'@'localhosts' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect
```

The command that throws this error is following:

```
sudo mysqldump --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf lom
```

I have allready added the username and passwort to /etc/mysql/my.cnf and made shure the cnf file has the right permissions:

```
[mysqldump]
user=db_user_backups
password=MyS3cretP4ssw0rD!
```

The username and password is correct, I can login with my sql client.

Does anyone have an idea whats im doing wrong?

(btw: please forgive me im a linux beginner ^^')

Answer (score 1):

With error "Access denied for user 'db_user-backups'@'localhosts'. You can connect to db and grant permission for user 'db_user-backups' with command example:

Connect to Mysql: mysql -u root -p:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO db_user-backups@'localhosts' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' with grant option;

flush privileges;
```

After you can reconnect with mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the port. I'm using MySQL 8.0 on Windows but similar issues apply on Ubuntu. Without a port argument I got the same error:

```
C:\Users\user>mysqldump -u root -p airlines_test > C:\...\test\airlines_test_dump.sql
Enter password: ******************
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

I fixed this by specifying the port to use: **`-P 3306`**:

```
C:\Users\user>mysqldump -u root -p -P 3306 airlines_test > C:\...\test\airlines_test_dump.sql
Enter password: ******************
```